# Access UNC from .net core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, unc

I need to read some files from UNC.

That shouldn't be a problem for .net framework but in case of .net core 2.2 that seems like mission impossible.
WindowsImpersonationContext is not supported by .net Core and impersonation done by some of the libraries (SimpleImpersonation,...) is not working.

Is there any solution for this "normal" task?